# Two Dimensional Array to Markdown Table Converter Implementation in C#

Tags: c#, strings, array, formatting, generics

I am attempting to implement a converter which can convert two dimensional array (such as `string[,]`) into [markdown table](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#Tables).

**The experimental implementation**

The experimental implementation of `Converter` class is as below.

```
public static class Converter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Align formats
    /// </summary>
    public enum Align
    {
        Right,
        Center,
        Left,
        Default
    }

    private static TOutput[,] ConvertAll<TInput, TOutput>(TInput[,] array, Converter<TInput, TOutput> converter)
    {
        //    null check
        if (ReferenceEquals(array, null))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(array)} is null");
        }

        if (ReferenceEquals(converter, null))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(converter)} is null");
        }

        var output = new TOutput[array.GetLongLength(0), array.GetLongLength(1)];
        for (long row = 0; row < array.GetLongLength(0); row++)
        {
            for (long column = 0; column < array.GetLongLength(1); column++)
            {
                output[row, column] = converter(array[row, column]);
            }
        }
        return output;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// ToMarkdownTable method with TInput type array
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="input">Input array</param>
    /// <param name="align">Align format of all columns</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string[] ToMarkdownTable<TInput>(TInput[,] input, Align align = Align.Default)
    {
        return ToMarkdownTable(ConvertAll(input, element => element.ToString()), align);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// ToMarkdownTable method with TInput type array and the parameter for assigning align format of each column
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="input">Input array</param>
    /// <param name="aligns">Align format of each column</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string[] ToMarkdownTable<TInput>(TInput[,] input, Align[] aligns)
    {
        return ToMarkdownTable(ConvertAll(input, element => element.ToString()), aligns);
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// ToMarkdownTable method
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="input">Input array</param>
    /// <param name="align">Align format of all columns</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string[] ToMarkdownTable(string[,] input, Align align = Align.Default)
    {
        Align[] format = new Align[input.GetLongLength(1)];
        Array.Fill(format, align);
        return ToMarkdownTable(input, format);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// ToMarkdownTable method with assigning align format of each column
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="input">Input array</param>
    /// <param name="aligns">Align format of each column</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string[] ToMarkdownTable(string[,] input, Align[] aligns)
    {
        //    Null check
        if (ReferenceEquals(input, null))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(input)} is null");
        }

        if (ReferenceEquals(input, null))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(aligns)} is null");
        }

        long width = input.GetLongLength(1);
        long height = input.GetLongLength(0);

        string[] output = new string[height + 1];

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.Append('|');
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            stringBuilder.Append(input[0, x]);
            stringBuilder.Append('|');
        }
        output[0] = stringBuilder.ToString();
        stringBuilder.Clear();

        stringBuilder.Append('|');
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            switch (aligns[x])
            {
                case Align.Right:
                    stringBuilder.Append("-:|");
                    break;
                case Align.Center:
                    stringBuilder.Append(":-:|");
                    break;
                case Align.Left:
                    stringBuilder.Append(":-|");
                    break;
                case Align.Default:
                    stringBuilder.Append("-|");
                    break;
                default:
                    stringBuilder.Append("-|");
                    break;
            }
            
        }
        output[1] = stringBuilder.ToString();
        stringBuilder.Clear();

        for (int y = 1; y < height; y++)
        {
            stringBuilder.Append('|');
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                stringBuilder.Append(input[y, x]);
                stringBuilder.Append('|');
            }
            output[y + 1] = stringBuilder.ToString();
            stringBuilder.Clear();
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

**Test cases**

The test cases of `Converter.ToMarkdownTable` methods include `string`, `sbyte`, `byte`, `short`, `ushort`, `char` and `int` type two dimensional arrays input.

```
//    string type two dimensional array case
Console.WriteLine("string type two dimensional array case");
string[,] test_string = { { "0", "1", "1", "1" },
                          { "2", "3", "1", "1" },
                          { "0", "1", "1", "1" }};

var format = new Converter.Align[test_string.GetLongLength(1)];
for (int i = 0; i < test_string.GetLongLength(1); i++)
{
    format[i] = Converter.Align.Center;
}
var MarkdownTable = Converter.ToMarkdownTable(test_string, Converter.Align.Center);
for (int i = 0; i < MarkdownTable.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(MarkdownTable[i]);
}
Console.WriteLine();

//    sbyte type two dimensional array case
Console.WriteLine("sbyte type two dimensional array case");
sbyte[,] test_sbyte = { { 0, 1, 1, 1 },
                        { 2, 3, 1, 1 },
                        { 0, 1, 1, 1 }};

var MarkdownTable_sbyte = Converter.ToMarkdownTable(test_sbyte, Converter.Align.Center);
for (int i = 0; i < MarkdownTable.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(MarkdownTable[i]);
}
Console.WriteLine();

//    byte type two dimensional array case
Console.WriteLine("byte type two dimensional array case");
byte[,] test_byte = { { 0, 1, 1, 1 },
                      { 2, 3, 1, 1 },
                      { 0, 1, 1, 1 }};

var MarkdownTable_byte = Converter.ToMarkdownTable(test_byte, Converter.Align.Center);
for (int i = 0; i < MarkdownTable.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(MarkdownTable[i]);
}
Console.WriteLine();

//    short type two dimensional array case
Console.WriteLine("short type two dimensional array case");
short[,] test_short = { { 0, 1, 1, 1 },
                        { 2, 3, 1, 1 },
                        { 0, 1, 1, 1 }};

var MarkdownTable_short = Converter.ToMarkdownTable(test_short, Converter.Align.Center);
for (int i = 0; i < MarkdownTable.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(MarkdownTable[i]);
}
Console.WriteLine();

//    ushort type two dimensional array case
Console.WriteLine("ushort type two dimensional array case");
ushort[,] test_ushort = { { 0, 1, 1, 1 },
                          { 2, 3, 1, 1 },
                          { 0, 1, 1, 1 }};

var MarkdownTable_ushort = Converter.ToMarkdownTable(test_ushort, Converter.Align.Center);
for (int i = 0; i < MarkdownTable.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(MarkdownTable[i]);
}
Console.WriteLine();

//    char type two dimensional array case
Console.WriteLine("char type two dimensional array case");
char[,] test_char = { { '0', '1', '1', '1' },
                      { '2', '3', '1', '1' },
                      { '0', '1', '1', '1' }};

var MarkdownTable_char = Converter.ToMarkdownTable(test_char, Converter.Align.Center);
for (int i = 0; i < MarkdownTable.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(MarkdownTable[i]);
}
Console.WriteLine();

//    int type two dimensional array case
Console.WriteLine("int type two dimensional array case");
int[,] test_int = { { 0, 1, 1, 1 },
                    { 2, 3, 1, 1 },
                    { 0, 1, 1, 1 }};

var MarkdownTable_int = Converter.ToMarkdownTable(test_int, Converter.Align.Center);
for (int i = 0; i < MarkdownTable.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(MarkdownTable[i]);
}
Console.WriteLine();
```

The output of the above tests:

```
string type two dimensional array case
|0|1|1|1|
|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|
|2|3|1|1|
|0|1|1|1|

sbyte type two dimensional array case
|0|1|1|1|
|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|
|2|3|1|1|
|0|1|1|1|

byte type two dimensional array case
|0|1|1|1|
|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|
|2|3|1|1|
|0|1|1|1|

short type two dimensional array case
|0|1|1|1|
|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|
|2|3|1|1|
|0|1|1|1|

ushort type two dimensional array case
|0|1|1|1|
|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|
|2|3|1|1|
|0|1|1|1|

char type two dimensional array case
|0|1|1|1|
|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|
|2|3|1|1|
|0|1|1|1|

int type two dimensional array case
|0|1|1|1|
|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|
|2|3|1|1|
|0|1|1|1|
```

If there is any possible improvement, please let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are my observations:

#### `Align`

- I think `Alignment` would be a better name. (*Align* is a verb where *Alignment* is a noun)
- Most of the time the `Default`, `Unknown` or `Invalid` is the first element in the enum

  - If you define an enum variable without specifying its value then it will be declared as 0

```cs
public enum Alignment { Default, Left, Center, Right }
```

#### `ConvertAll`

- `ReferenceEquals(array, null)`: This can be simplified like this: `array is null`
- `ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(array)} is null")`: Here the constructor anticipates the **name of the parameter**, not the *message*. So the correct way would look like this:

```cs
if (array is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(array));
```

- `array.GetLongLength(0)`: As you have done it in the `ToMarkdownTable` you can declare a helper variable to store this value and reuse it multiple times:

```cs
var rowCount = array.GetLongLength(0);
var columnCount = array.GetLongLength(1);
var output = new TOutput[rowCount, columnCount];
```

- Nested for loops: It is minor, but you can get rid of the block operators:

```cs
for (var row = 0; row < rowCount; row++)
    for (var column = 0; column < columnCount; column++)
        output[row, column] = converter(array[row, column]);
```

So the whole `ConvertAll` can be refactored like this:

```cs
private static TOutput[,] ConvertAll<TInput, TOutput>(TInput[,] array, Converter<TInput, TOutput> converter)
{
    if (array is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(array));
    if (converter is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(converter));

    var rowCount = array.GetLongLength(0);
    var columnCount = array.GetLongLength(1);
    var output = new TOutput[rowCount, columnCount];

    for (var row = 0; row < rowCount; row++)
        for (var column = 0; column < columnCount; column++)
            output[row, column] = converter(array[row, column]);

    return output;
}
```

#### `ToMarkDownTable` *where the core logic resides*

- Yet again the null checks can be simplified

  - The second null check is done against `input`, please fix it to use `alings` there
- `width` and `height`: I would suggest to stick with the terms `row` and `column` because we are talking about table.
- `stringBuilder.Clear()`: Even though it does work, it indicates that your separation of concerns is not good.

  - I do suggest to introduce several helper method and use them like this:

```cs
public static string[] ToMarkDownTable(string[,] input, Alignment[] aligns)
{
    if (input is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(input));
    if (aligns is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(aligns));

    var rowCount = input.GetLongLength(0);
    var output = new string[rowCount + 1];

    output[0] = ToTableHeader(input);
    output[1] = ToTableCellAlignments(input, aligns);

    for (var row = 1; row < rowCount; row++)
        output[row + 1] = ToTableRow(input, row);

    return output;
}
```

#### Header

- `stringBuilder.Append('|');`: I suggest to introduce a class level constant to hold the cell separator:

```cs
private const char CellSeparator = '|';
```

- With this the header generation would be string literal free:

```cs
private static string ToTableHeader(string[,] input)
{
    var tableHeaderBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    tableHeaderBuilder.Append(CellSeparator);

    for (var column = 0; column < input.GetLongLength(1); column++)
    {
        tableHeaderBuilder.Append(input[0, column]);
        tableHeaderBuilder.Append(CellSeparator);
    }

    return tableHeaderBuilder.ToString();
}
```

- If your `input` would be a multi-dimensional array, not a jagged one then the `input` could be a single dimensional array. That would increase the separation.

#### Cell Alignments

- `stringBuilder.Append`: This has been repeated way too many times.

  - Your branching should be scoped to the data (should NOT include the operation).
  - With that you would be able to use switch expression:

```cs
private static string ToTableCellAlignments(string[,] input, Alignment[] aligns)
{
    var tableCellAlignmentBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    tableCellAlignmentBuilder.Append(CellSeparator);

    for (var column = 0; column < input.GetLongLength(1); column++)
    {
        var separator = aligns[column] switch
        {
            Alignment.Right => $"-:{CellSeparator}",
            Alignment.Center => $":-:{CellSeparator}",
            Alignment.Left => $":-{CellSeparator}",
            Alignment.Default => $"-{CellSeparator}",
            _ => $"-{CellSeparator}"
        };

        tableCellAlignmentBuilder.Append(separator);
    }

    return tableCellAlignmentBuilder.ToString();
}
```

#### Row

- I've decided to extract away only a single row generation instead of all rows

  - This simplifies the row generation logic
  - *and can be easily altered to utilize multi dimensional array*

```cs
private static string ToTableRow(string[,] input, int row)
{
    var tableRowBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    tableRowBuilder.Append(CellSeparator);

    for (var column = 0; column < input.GetLongLength(1); column++)
    {
        tableRowBuilder.Append(input[row, column]);
        tableRowBuilder.Append(CellSeparator);
    }
    return tableRowBuilder.ToString();
}
```

---

In case of multi-dimensional arrays the core logic would look like this:

- So, in my opinion it might make sense to convert your jagged array to multi-dimensional

```cs
private static string[] ToMarkDownTable(string[][] input, Alignment[] aligns)
{
    if (input is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(input));
    if (aligns is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(aligns));

    var rowCount = input.GetLongLength(0);
    var columnCount = input.GetLongLength(1);
    var output = new string[rowCount + 1];

    output[0] = ToTableHeader(input[0]);
    output[1] = ToTableCellAlignments(columnCount, aligns);

    for (var row = 1; row < rowCount; row++)
        output[row + 1] = ToTableRow(input[row]);

    return output;
}

private const char CellSeparator = '|';
private static string ToTableHeader(string[] headers)
{
    var tableHeaderBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    tableHeaderBuilder.Append(CellSeparator);

    foreach (var header in headers)
    {
        tableHeaderBuilder.Append(header);
        tableHeaderBuilder.Append(CellSeparator);
    }

    return tableHeaderBuilder.ToString();
}

private static string ToTableCellAlignments(long columns, Alignment[] aligns)
{
    var tableCellAlignmentBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    tableCellAlignmentBuilder.Append(CellSeparator);

    for (var column = 0; column < columns; column++)
    {
        var separator = aligns[column] switch
        {
            Alignment.Right => $"-:{CellSeparator}",
            Alignment.Center => $":-:{CellSeparator}",
            Alignment.Left => $":-{CellSeparator}",
            _ => $"-{CellSeparator}"
        };

        tableCellAlignmentBuilder.Append(separator);
    }

    return tableCellAlignmentBuilder.ToString();
}

private static string ToTableRow(string[] cells)
{
    var tableRowBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    tableRowBuilder.Append(CellSeparator);

    foreach (var cell in cells)
    {
        tableRowBuilder.Append(cell);
        tableRowBuilder.Append(CellSeparator);
    }
    return tableRowBuilder.ToString();
}
```

---

**UPDATE** Further simplification of `ToTableCellAlignments`:

```cs
private static string ToTableCellAlignments(Alignment[] alignments)
{
    var tableCellAlignmentBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    tableCellAlignmentBuilder.Append(CellSeparator);

    for (var alignment in alignments)
    {
        var separator = alignment switch
        {
            Alignment.Right => $"-:{CellSeparator}",
            Alignment.Center => $":-:{CellSeparator}",
            Alignment.Left => $":-{CellSeparator}",
            _ => $"-{CellSeparator}"
        };

        tableCellAlignmentBuilder.Append(separator);
    }

    return tableCellAlignmentBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Prerequisite: `ToMarkDownTable` has to check `aligns.Length` against `array.GetLongLength(1)` if they aren't matching then it could throw an `ArgumentException`.